# Showing that any irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-representation has a $1$-dimensional kernel for its nilpotent elements.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

*I want to prove, that for any irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-representation $(\rho, V)$ in the standart basis $\{e,f,h\}$ we have that $dim( ker(\rho(e))=1$, and same for $f$.*

---

**My idea:**

First we recall some definitions: Recall that $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ has the standart basis $\{e,f,h\}$ with relations
$$[h,e]=2e, [h,f]=-2f, [e,f]=h.$$
We are assuming that $V$ finite dimensional. Also, since $h$ is semisimple, it acts diagonally on $V$ and since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, this yields a decomposition of $V$ as direct sum of eigenspaces $V_{\lambda} = \{v\in V \mid h.v = \lambda v\}$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Whenever we have that $V_{\lambda} \neq 0$,
we call $\lambda$ a **weight** of $h$ in $V$ and $V_{\lambda}$ a **weight space**.

We now have, that $V$ is a irreducible  $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-module. Choose a maximal vector, say $v_0$ and set $v_{-1}=0, v_i = (1/i!)f^i.v_0$. According to Humphrey´s Lemma (page 32), we have the follwing formulas:
$$h.v_i = (\lambda - 2i)v_i,$$
$$f.v_i =(i+1)v_{i+1},$$
$$e.v_i = (\lambda - i +1)v_{i-1}$$
for $i \geq 0$. In particular for $i=0$ it yields
$$e.v_0 = (\lambda +1)v_{-1}=0$$
My idea was to use this, in order to show that
$$ker(\rho(e)) = span\{v_i \mid i=0 \} = \mathbb{C}v_0.$$
Unfortunately it didn´t work out.

Comment: Why are you assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional? Besides, I don't see how you justify that $\ker(\rho(e))=\operatorname{span}\{v_0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$-dimensional irreducible representation $V=\langle v_0,\ldots ,v_{n-1}\rangle$ can be given by the formulas $\rho(h)v_i=(n-1-2i)v_i$, $\rho(e)v_i=(n-i)v_{i-1}$ and $\rho(f)v_i=(i+1)v_{i+1}$.
Then the matrices of $\rho(e)$, $\rho(f),\rho(h)$ are given by
$$
  \rho(e)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & n-1 \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0    
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
\rho(f)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
n-1 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
  \rho(h)=\begin{pmatrix} n-1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & n-3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & \ddots & 3-n & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1-n    
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $\ker(\rho(e))={\rm span}(v_0)$ is $1$-dimensional, as well as $\ker(\rho(f))={\rm span}(v_{n-1})$.